# Ajax call returning empty string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

im trying to post to php using jquery but the success function is returning an empty string.

jquery:

```
function post() {
  value = posts[index].id;
  console.log(value)
  $.ajax({
    url: 'post.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {value: 'value'},
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result)
    }
  })
}
```

php:

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
  var_dump($_POST);
}
```

Comment: What does the AJAX request show when sending the request? (Your data also appears inverted `data: {'value': value}` I'd think you want)

Comment: Try to add datatype in request `dataType: 'html',`

Comment: this is what its showing https://i.imgur.com/eKDE8h5.png, its also passing the data correctly

Comment: @groovy_guy that does not seem to work

Comment: Response tab is empty?

Comment: oh yea the response tab is empty